# jupyter notebook freezes after plotting in a new window

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I have the following simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython


# Get the name of the shell to handle the when the program is running in iython
shell = get_ipython().__class__.__name__


dataset_url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m-mehdi/pandas_tutorials/main/weekly_stocks.csv') 


df = pd.read_csv(dataset_url, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date') 


if shell == 'ZMQInteractiveShell':
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')

df.plot(y='MSFT', figsize=(9,6))
plt.show(block=True)
plt.close()

print("hello")
```

that hangs jupyter notebook even after the plot window is closed.

Jupyter notebook seems to be stuck at the

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

line even after the plot window is closed.

When run on a terminal the code runs fine.

I have an anaconda fresh install.
What should I do to avoid the problem?

I could run the program setting the plot display inline but I will miss some functionalities that I need